# Can't filter with select in smart-table

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Trying to filter a table using a *select* and *ng-options* but not successful. I've got a **plunker** showing the problem. Anyone who can see what is going on?

http://plnkr.co/edit/WlojiFw26gqUoEDXOeQd?p=preview

**My Select:**

```
<select class="form-control"
    st-search="code"
    st-input-event="change"
    st-delay="0"
    ng-model="selectedStatusFilter"
    ng-options="f.code as f.text for f in codeOptions">
</select>
```

**My options:**

```
$scope.codeOptions = [{
    'text': 'On',
    'code': 'On'
  }, {
    'text': 'Off',
    'code': 'Off'
  }, {
    'text': 'Cat',
    'code': 'Cat'
  }, {
    'text': 'All',
    'code': ''
  }]
```

**Typical item in collection:**

```
code : "On"
firstName : "Laurent"
id : 9
lastName : "Renard"
```

So what I'm hoping to happens is that the value of the Select gets interperated as a filter on the code property of the items in collection. So when `"On"` is selected only items with `code : 'On'` are shown, and with `All` selected because the value there is `""` we should see all items.

- Using Angular version 1.6.4
- Using Smart-Table 2.1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alternative way you can use `<option>` and `ng-repeat` without any `ng-model`

```
 <select class="form-control" st-search="code">
                <option ng-repeat="f in codeOptions" 
                ng-selected="codeOptions.indexOf(f) == 3"
                value="{{f.code}}">{{f.text}}</option>
</select>
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/awZRxoEISeEzsQDYg3F0?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: This works except that the filter isn't evaluated initially. Nothing happens until after we change the select. Try changing the selected initial option to index 0. Notice that it still shows everything until we change the dropdown. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

In the smart filter documentation there is a way defined on how to do this, Refer the link [Smart Table Filtering](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#filter-strict-mode), So in this link its tells us to use the attribute `st-set-filter` on the smart table declarartion element. Another thing is, in `select using ng-options` we will get the datatype included in the `ng-model` of the select element, to remove this, you can use `track by f.code`, So the HTML changes are:

```
<section st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection" st-set-filter="myCustomFilter"> 
        <select class="form-control"
        st-search="code"
        st-input-event="change"
        st-delay="0"
        ng-model="selectedStatusFilter"
        ng-options="f.code as f.text for f in codeOptions track by f.code"></select>
        {{displayedCollection}}
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
```

The JS contains a filter declaration taken from the docs.

```
app.filter('myCustomFilter', function($filter){
    return function(input, predicate){
        console.log(input, predicate);
        return $filter('filter')(input, predicate, true);
    }
});
```

Finally below is a demo for the same.

<kbd>**Plunkr Demo**</kbd>

Please let me know if you face any issues!

Comment: This works except that the filter isn't evaluated initially. Nothing happens until after we change the select. `$scope.selectedStatusFilter = $scope.codeOptions[0];` But it still shows everything.